# Can't open outlook with attachement

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, runtime.exec

i am trying to open outlook with attachment as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            new String[] {"rundll32",
            "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler",
            "mailto:" + "&attachment=" + "c:\\test.txt"}
            );
```

outlook opens, but it don't get the attachment, i don't know why ? please advise.
also is it possible to give the attachment web url from my application ?

like: http://myapp.com/files/123 (this link triggers file download)

Answer (score 1):

mailto protocol does not support attachments. You would need to use the Outlook Object Model to explicitly create an instance of the Outlook.Application object, call Application.CreateItem() and then add the attachment using MailItem.Attachments.Add. You can then display the message using MailItem.Display.

Comment: are there any references for that ? i think above code will open outlook on server, right ? and to open outlook on client machine above code have to be called in an applet ?

Comment: Yes, that needs to run in the client side JavaScript inside the browser if you are using IE. It will not work in FF, Chrome or Safari since they don't support COM objects. And in even in IE, your site must be trusted to be able to create COM objects.